# Image Preview on hover in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Below is my code for an image preview on hover. It preview the image in the original size which I don't want.

I'd like to have the previews be a fixed width, say 300px. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
 this.imagePreview = function(){    
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");

    });         
};
```

Comment: `$("body").append("<p id='preview'><img width='300' src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");`

Comment: On a side note, I wouldn't insert values like that.  You're setting yourself up for an XSS attack.  Do something like `$("<p id='preview'><img width='300' alt='Image Preview'><div></div></p>") .find('img').attr('src',this.href).end() .find('div').text(this.title).end() .appendTo(document.body);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line:

```
$("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");
```

You can add:

```
$("#preview>img").width(300);
```

Comment: You're resizing the `<p>`.  He needs to be resizing the `<img>`.